# Fitting Vogel's formula for phyllotaxis to an actual plant.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, biology

A simple model for the arrangement of florets in a sunflower [was given by Vogel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower):

$r = c\sqrt{n}$

$\theta = 137.508 n$

Where $r$ and $\theta$ are polar coordinates, $c$ is some constant and $n$ is the index number of the floret. In this image each floret is marked by a blue point:

[image: phyllotaxis of a sunflower]

I am trying to recreate it. The problem is:

- How do I determine the correct constants to generate the flower in the photo?

I do have information about the flower such as the position of the florets. I will do the calculations in *Mathematica*.

**Update.** I later [managed to do this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39772/fitting-vogners-formula-for-phyllotaxis-to-the-image-of-a-flower) but the results weren't impressive, probably because the mode simply isn't that good.

Comment: `Vogel` = `Vogner` ?

Comment: @Did Thanks, I corrected the typo. Also added a link to a post about how this can be done in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing anything else about the problem domain, I'd take a look at the [Nelder-Mead method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method).  It's general and robust.

As far as what to vary, here's what I'd start with.

- The origin of your polar coordinate system.  Where is the center of your spiral?  Does it have to be located on one of the florets, or not?
- Your scale parameter, $c$.  This determines, in general, how far apart the florets are.  It would be best to relate this to the physical size of the flower, but expressing it in terms of image pixels would work, too.
- Your starting index.  Maybe you'd get a better fit starting with $n=5$.  Or maybe the model dictates that you start at $n=1$.
- Your offset angle.  You will probably need to offset all of the angles by some constant angle $\theta_0$ to account for the fact that you took the picture at some orientation, rather than $1^{\circ}$ off.

Comment: But what do I optimize/minimize? Should I generate a set using some parameters n, c etc. and then compare them with the positions of the florets in the image using a norm, and minimize that? The 2-norm?

Comment: The function you'll minimize will be something like a sum of least squares.  You have your measured floret locations, and you have a set of predicted floret locations from the model.  Let the model fly and see how close you get (sum of all of the least squares).  Adjust one or more parameters and see if that sum goes up or down.  That's what the Nelder-Mead method does.  It goes through your parameter space and crawls its way down to a minimum.